# GRUB2 Doesn't see Ubuntu - triple boot Win10 Androidx86 Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, android

When I installed android x86 on my computer, I opted to have it install the grub2 which boots both to windows10 and android without issue. I then decided to install ubuntu, but I can't get into ubuntu to run update-grub.

Previously on this computer when dual booting win/ubuntu, if I selected UEFI boot in the bios, it would boot windows and if I selected legacy, it would boot ubuntu. Now the legacy option goes to an emergency grub.

I'll try a live cd today.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Installing operating systems in different boot-mode (UEFI/legacy) on the same machine always leads to headache.

Comment: You might need to run `update-grub` from Android, if that's possible. If not, you might consider looking into my [rEFInd boot manager,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) at least as a stopgap -- you can put it on a USB flash drive or CD-R (download links for both are [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html)) and boot from that, which will probably boot both Ubuntu and Windows, and maybe Android. If that works, you could install rEFInd from Ubuntu or try to get Ubuntu's GRUB working via manual configuration or [Boot Repair.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)